# react - add a classname to a specific element by clicking the button

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to reactjs. A sign in and sign up component is created. When clicking the button, a classname is supposed to be added to the specific element, in my case, signWrapper. I've tried few ways but it doesn't work. How do I add a classname to a specific element by clicking the button?

My code is on the codesandbox. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hertz-pmk23?file=/src/SignInAndSignUp.js:0-2298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used your onClick function in a wrong way . you have to invoke this .

instead of this

```
onClick = { () => this.handleClick}
```

you have to do this

```
onClick = { () => this.handleClick()}
```

and handle your onClick like this

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });  // to toggle the state
};
```

here is the working example https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-star-ghp7h?file=/src/SignInAndSignUp.js:283-360

Answer (score 0):

Invoke your `onClick` function like so:

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

```
handleClick = () => {
  // I added ...this.state so it doesn't affect any other state variables you may add
  this.setState({ ...this.state, active: !this.state.active });
};
```

Also, check out the library [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx). It's very helpful when you have multiple classes needing to be activated or unactivated based on conditionals. This would look something more like the following:

```
className={clsx('signWrapper', { 'right-panel-active': active })}
```